# Configure an Airport to connect to internet via a wireless hotspot?

Tags: wifi, router, airport, tethering

The situation:  I have free access to Time Warner (TWC) and Optimum hotspots around the USA.  Conveniently one is located within range to my apartment.  I would like to setup an Airport Extreme or Express to use this wireless internet connection instead of the traditional way of plugging in via ethernet.

In my Optimum account settings I can register a MAC address (i.e. my Airport's MAC address) that allows me to bypass any authentication.  Is there no mode in Airport Utility that allows me to simply source my internet connection from another wireless network?  My end result is to have a normal, functioning, NAT / DHCP network in my home.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

I would use any [old router to bridge from the hotspot into your house](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-turn-an-old-router-into-a-wireless-bridge/), making sure that the bridge is in optimal distance of the Provider Hotspot.

Once I have that configured and I know I have connectivity to the internet, I would hardwire the Airport Extreme into the bridge to have the home networking functionality, as set up through Airport Utility.